# Issue in Data filled in Spinner from Database

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner

I have an External Database into assets folder. I have been successful into loading it on my Emulator and performing operations on it.
I also know how to fill data using queries in Spinner and ListView.

The main issue: I am running a query which gives me all data from the table. I store them in a Bean class. Now i have successfully filled one of the column data into a spinner.

BUT, when i open the spinner, i don't get Database values but object name into spinner

**FOR e.g -- com.mypackageName.BeanPackage.BeanClass@411da123**

I get the whole spinner full of this, not the Data which is in Database( e.g 13, 13/1) .

My Code :

Query in DBHelper Class :

```
public Cursor getBusNumbers() {
    // date="21-10-2013";

    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    return db.rawQuery("select * from table", null);
}
```

In My Main Activity :

Adapter code :

```
 adapter = new Adapter(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array);

   route.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

My GetView method:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = ((LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
                        .inflate(layout, null);
            }


            final Bean item = items.get(position);
            final TextView km = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

            km.setText(item.getRouteNumber());
            km.setTextSize(22);
            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

Method which fills the Array :

```
private void loadFieldDatabase() {

        Cursor c = dbhelper.getBusNumbers();
        if (c != null && c.getCount() > 0) {
            c.moveToFirst();
            for (int count = 0; count < c.getCount(); count++) {
                Bean detail = new Bean();

                detail.setRouteNumber(c.getString(c
                        .getColumnIndex("route_number")));

                array.add(detail);
                c.moveToNext();
            }
            c.close();
            //dbhelper.close();
        }
```

Comment: i think call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() before you set adapter

Comment: post code of inserting data to array

Comment: Added the array Insertion method. Any specific reason why would object name be loaded in Spinner instead of DB data?

Comment: what are you doing in your Bean class??

Comment: Its has getter and setter methods. Nothing else

Comment: If i use the ListView with the exact same Adapter, array and Bean class, I get results. Only with the Spinner, i m getting those object names.

Answer (score 0):

Here in  your code your setting the Bean object into the Text view insted of which item you need to set that.

Try this code this may help you.

```
private void loadSpinnerCourse() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<String> lables = getAllCourse();

        // Creating adapter for spinner
        dataAdapterCourse = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);
        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        dataAdapterCourse
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        mLesson_course.setAdapter(dataAdapterCourse);
    }

    private List<String> getAllCourse() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
        mCoureseIdList = new ArrayList<String>();

        ExamDatabaseConnector dbConnector = new ExamDatabaseConnector(
                getActivity());
        dbConnector.open();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM courses_stud";

        Cursor cursor = dbConnector.database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                mCoureseIdList.add(cursor.getString(0));
                labels.add(cursor.getString(1));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // closing connection
        cursor.close();
        dbConnector.database.close();

        // returning lables
        return labels;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Cursor cursor = db.getAllBhashat();
    SpinnerArr = new String[cursor.getCount()+1];


    SpinnerArr[0] = "<-SELECT->";


    if(cursor.moveToNext()){
        int i = 1;
        do {
            SpinnerArr[i] = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex("LocalityTitle_E"));



            i++;
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_sorCat = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, SpinnerArr);
    Spinner.setAdapter(adapter_sorCat);
    adapter_sorCat
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
 }
```